# Will the autmatic full reset of Windows 10 damage Ubunutu (or grub) [UEFI]?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi

as I really needed both systems, I lost over a month to set up a dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows 10 on a brand new Asus laptop. After many attempts, I had to do something very risky. I uninstalled everything I had from the SSD, install Ubunutu first and then install Windows 10 Pro which was not installing the drivers correctly. Then I installed Windows 10 Home from Pro to a version I had my license on, and it kinda worked. The laptop has really good specs. Unfortunately, Windows is lagging, overheats, and some bugs because I think it didn't install all the drivers correctly. Anyway, my last hope is reset Windows. But I am worried that I will mess up Ubuntu. Ubuntu is working perfectly. On the disk, first comes Ubuntu. There is a small amount of space between the systems that does nothing. So, SSD drives, UEFI mode, Ubuntu, then Windows 10 on the system... How safe am I in attempting to do a full reset of Windows 10 (the automatically one they offer in the menu, not a fresh install)?

Comment: Yes there is always a chance that something does not go as planned. You might make a mistake, there could be a power interruption.  This is why it's essential to keep good backups. Considering that you have said that it has taken you multiple attempts in the past to correctly install the operating system, I would say that there is a high chance that something could go wrong.  It would be better if you would ask about the actual problem(s) you are facing, since it really should not be so problematic to install either OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am aware that it's risky. But there are not many things that could go wrong on my side. My plan was to go to the Windows settings, click on Full reset and wait. I was more interested to know, is it more likely that a full reset would mess up the whole Ubunutu (not just grub), in the UEFI mode (because I've read that with BIO that would be inevitable.